# php: php simple dom parser question

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

i'm using the php simple dom parser and found a little issue:

when the selector returns only one element, i also need to run a foreach loop for it.
is there a simpler way to do it?

thanks

Comment: like in jQuery - when u get only one element you can directly access it by default.

Comment: You need to post your use case with code if we are to be any help to you

Comment: all jQuery functions work on a multiset, meaning they don't care if it's one element or every single dom element. Give us a test case of what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: very simple:
<div class=widget><input type=text value=bla></div>

my code is: 
$txt = $ctl->find("input");
it's only one element but i can't access it like in jQuery with: echo $txt->value .. so i need to run a foreach loop everytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual says](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)
`find()` has a second parameter for exactly that:

> mixed find ( string $selector [, int $index] )
>
> Find elements by the CSS selector. Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise return an array of object.

So in your case,

```
$txt = $ctl->find("input", 0);
```

should do the job.

[SimpleHTMLDOM API reference](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm#api)